# Azure create one drive file on post request to logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am creating an Azure Logic App which will trigger on Post request which'll create a file on one drive using the data passed to it.

I am requesting through Postman, attaching the file in form data. But I don't know how to handle this request and get file content to create a file in logic app.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic app engine natively supports only `Application/json` and `Text/plain` content type, but all the other content types are also supported.

If you pass any other type of content, logic app engine will convert the content to binary base64 encoded string with appropriate metadata so that the data isn't lost while moving through the workflow.

All you need to do is use appropriate converter to convert it back.

For more details, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type).